# Formatting XML for output file in a tree doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, xml, forms

I tried to do this in many ways using a php code to save to xml file in a TREE FORMAT, but no success. Something is wrong, I don't know. The output format remains a long string like this:

```
<products><product id="p02"><name>Name 2</name><price currency="USD">200</price></product></products>
```

I need some help. Here is my code:

```
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])) {
    $products = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $products->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $products->formatOutput = true;
$doc->load('data/product.xml');
$product = $products->addChild('product');
$product->addAttribute('id', $_POST['id']);
$product->addChild('name', $_POST['name']);
$product->addChild('price', $_POST['price']);
file_put_contents('data/product.xml', $doc->saveXML());
header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: </products> is missing in your xml

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes that is output he said, not input

Comment: @AntonioAbrantes I forgot put the entire code. But it stills doesn't work

Comment: if the solution is ok please dont forget to press green flag to close question

Comment: Can you explain that further? What's the difference between "a long string" and whatever you expect?

Comment: @NicoHaase By long string he means that his current output is a single line, whereas he wants it to be formatted. See here: https://pastebin.com/ank7Ukws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])){

    $products = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $products->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $products->formatOutput = true;

    // $doc->load('data/product.xml');

    $product = $products->createElement('product');
    $product->setAttribute('id', $_POST['id']);
    $name = $products->createElement('name', $_POST['name']);
    $price = $products->createElement('price', $_POST['price']);

    $products->appendChild($product);
    $product->appendChild($name);
    $product->appendChild($price);

    file_put_contents('data/product.xml', $products->saveXML());

    // echo $products->saveXML();
}
?>
```

Here is demo on [ideone](https://ideone.com/6eue4v) without POST parameters

This is my output on local machine, works with post parameters

[image: code output]

***Edit:*** As requested here is the code to preserve older data

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submitSave'])){

    // Disable errors due to empty xml files
    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_WARNING);

    $domDoc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $domDoc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $domDoc->formatOutput = true;

    // load xml file
    try {
        $domDoc->load('./data/product.xml');
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        //throw $th;
    }

    if($domDoc->getElementsByTagName('products')->length>0){
        // If we already have products tag defined
        $products = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName('products')[0];
    }else{
        // If we don't have any products tag, i.e. file is empty
        $products = $domDoc->createElement('products');
    }

    // Create child node for product and set id(attribute), name(child), price(child)
    $product = $domDoc->createElement('product');
    $product->setAttribute('id', $_POST['id']);
    $name = $domDoc->createElement('name', $_POST['name']);
    $price = $domDoc->createElement('price', $_POST['price']);

    $domDoc->appendChild($products);
    $products->appendChild($product);
    $product->appendChild($name);
    $product->appendChild($price);

    file_put_contents('./data/product.xml', $domDoc->saveXML());

}
?>
```

This is output on my local machine:

[image: code output]

Comment: It worked, but now, every time I add a new entry, the oldest data is overwritten by new one.  :(

Comment: @Ecker I have updated code to support multiple products. It will now parse existing xml and append your new product within. It this helps please upvote and mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

The output file is product.xml. For testing I use http://localhost/teste.php?id=p02&name=Name2&price=200&currency=USD

```
$xmlstr= "<products></products>";
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$product = $sxe->addChild('product');
$product->addAttribute('id', $_REQUEST['id']);
$product->addChild('name', $_REQUEST['name']);
$price = $product->addChild('price', $_REQUEST['price']);
$price->addAttribute('currency', $_REQUEST['currency']);
$xmlOutput = $sxe->asXML();
file_put_contents('product.xml',$xmlOutput);
```

Comment: It stills show the strings in one line instead of in a tree output.

Comment: You are brazillian. So am I. I'm trying to say to you  that I want to save the strings above (childs) in a tree row (numa hierarquia). Because the output is an XML file with one single line (that's aweful|!)